# Reverse returning values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

OK, given the following dataset:

```
ID , name    , lineManagerKey, lineManagerName
 1 , Joe     , null          , null
 2 , Herbert ,    1          , Joe
 3 , John    ,    1          , Joe
 4 , George  , null          , null
 5 , Paul    , null          , null
 6 , Ringo   , null          , null
 7 , Frank   , null          , null
 8 , Jeff    ,    7          , Frank
```

I want to return the following:

```
Manager,Minion
Joe,Herbert
Joe,John
Frank,Jeff
```

Every way I am thinking of the possible query it seems to want to return multiple rows? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Why do you have both lineManagerKey and lineManagerName? It sounds like you have a LineManager table which already maps keys to names?

Comment: You can pretty much ignore the Line Manager Name, but I added it in, in this case so you visualise the data structure better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select lineManagerName as Manager,name as Minion from table where lineManagerName is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for that... I was going round in circles and somehow not actually finding the solution.